# R: enumerating sequences of permutations

Tags: r

I want to enumerate the distinct sequences of different permutations, and I'm using the function `permn`. I understand for 2!, I can just use `permn(2)` and that will enumerate `1, 2` and `2, 1`.

```
> library(combinat)
> permn(2)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 2 1
```

I want to do the same thing for the numbers 7 and 8. So what should I pass into the function so that it will return something like this?

```
> permn(...)
[[1]]
[1] 7 8

[[2]]
[1] 8 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
permn(c(7,8))
#[[1]]
#[1] 7 8
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 8 7
```